# Java LinkedHashMap to scala Map conversion and recursive conversion

Tags: java, scala

If `mapAsScalaMap` is an implicit function then why do we have to use it explicitly? And why is recursive conversion not happening ?

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._  
val javaObj = yamlObj.asInstanceOf[java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, String]]]

val map: collection.mutable.Map[String, collection.mutable.Map[String, String]] = javaObj << type mismatch
```

Isn't the above supposed to work because I imported all implicit Java conversions?

If I use `mapAsScalaMap(javaObj)` then it works but then it doesn't convert nested `LinkedHashMap` into a Scala map.

Comment: Scala's javaconversions don't work for nested conversions but an explicit conversion can be done for them using JavaConverters as shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981983/how-to-convert-a-nested-scala-collection-to-a-nested-java-collection not in the direction you want but can be adapted to convert nested java map to scala.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit conversions don't happen "inside" the parameters of a parametrized type, and don't happen recursively.

You can convert the values using something like this:

```
val map: collection.Map[String, collection.mutable.Map[String, String]] = javaObj.mapValues(x => x: collection.mutable.Map[String, String])
```

(note that `map` does not offer a mutable interface - it's a view on the original map but it can't be modified because scala doesn't know how to run the transformation in reverse).