# Cannot resolve symbol asJava : Intellij idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've been doing scala coding on intellij idea. All was well until I added this piece of code (copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32380463/444644 ) :

```
  def toJava(x: Any): Any = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    x match {
      case y: scala.collection.MapLike[_, _, _] =>
        y.map { case (d, v) => toJava(d) -> toJava(v) } asJava
      case y: scala.collection.SetLike[_,_] =>
        y map { item: Any => toJava(item) } asJava
      case y: Iterable[_] =>
        y.map { item: Any => toJava(item) } asJava
      case y: Iterator[_] =>
        toJava(y.toIterable)
      case _ =>
        x
    }
  }
```

This results in two "error" highlights for the first two asJava calls above. But the code compiles and runs fine. How to fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you show screenshots of the errors?

Comment: Added screenshot.. Tooltip on the red stuff says: "Cannot resolve symbol asJava"

Comment: Curious. If you take out all the `asJava` statements, as well as the `import` statement, you'll find that it still compiles. Perhaps the compiler is allowing legacy, but unneeded, code but the IntilliJ interpreter doesn't have that level of smarts.

Comment: try adding the `.` before asJava, and before tha map too: `x.map{...}.asJava`. Sometime IJ has trouble understanding when the dot are removed

Comment: @Juh_ Adding a dot does not help.

Comment: @jwvh I'm sure it compiles, but the code will not work as intended in such a case.

Answer (score -1):

Add an import in particular code file

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

Comment: The import is already there

Comment: please use comments when you are not sure