# Convert Scala nested Map to Java nested util.Map

Tags: java, scala

I use Scala in my project and want to integrate with Stripe, but it provides only Java API. For example, to create session I use:

```
val params = new util.HashMap[String, AnyRef]
val paymentMethodTypes = new util.ArrayList[String]
paymentMethodTypes.add("card")
params.put("payment_method_types", paymentMethodTypes)
params.put("mode", "setup")
params.put("success_url", "https://test.app/success")
params.put("cancel_url", "https://test.app/cancel")
val session = Session.create(params)
```

This code works perfectly, but it's very ugly and contains a lot of boilerplate. I'd like to use a Scala `Map[String, AnyRef]` and create session as follows:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val params2: Map[String, AnyRef] = Map(
  "payment_method_types" -> List("card"),
  "mode" -> "setup",
  "success_url" -> "https://test.app/success",
  "cancel_url" -> "https://test.app/cancel"
)
val session2 = Session.create(mapAsJavaMap[String, AnyRef](params2))
```

It turns out that `mapAsJavaMap` can't convert nested objects in the Map. Is there a way to convert arbitrary Scala Map with other Maps and Lists inside to their Java equivalents?

Comment: What version of scala? What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JavaConverters` has been deprecated. Try `CollectionConverters`.

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

def convertMap[K](scalaMap :Map[K,AnyRef]) :java.util.Map[K,AnyRef] =
  scalaMap.map{ case (k,v) => v match {
    case m:Map[_,AnyRef] => (k, convertMap(m))  //recursive
    case l:List[_]       => (k, l.asJava)       //java.util.List[_]
    case _               => (k, v)              //unchanged
  }}.asJava
```

Not sure if this will actually work for you, what with all the values being type `AnyRef`. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I get `non-variable type argument AnyRef in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[_,AnyRef] (the underlying of Map[_,AnyRef]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JavaConverters](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) and here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678194/11843739) how you can convert collections recursively.